# Allocate and free memory of an array from structure

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have following structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *name[10];
    char *msg[100];
} Log;
```

How I can free the name and msg arrays from Log structure? I know free is used only for dynamic allocation, and dynamic allocation doesn't work in structures. What I can do?

Tryed this but give error:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *name[] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    char *msg[] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
} Log;
```

Who can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: You have tagged this as C++, but the code is most certainly C. Which do you want an answer in?

Comment: Depends. First off, a `char* x[]` is a char-ptr array. `char *name[10]` allocates 10 char ptrs, which is not what you want to do. `typedef struct {char name[10]; char msg[100];} Log;` will allocate these fields as inline to the structure (`sizeof(Log)>=110`). Else you'll need to provide an init and cleanup function for the struct. Personally, in such cases I make the user only interact with handles and never the struct directly.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is per definitionem 1, so don't write it. Also, [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a structure doesn't allocate memory for its members. Memory is allocated when an instance of a structure is created. So

```
typedef struct
{
    char *name[10];
    char *msg[100];
} Log;
```

doesn't allocate memory for `name` and `msg`, it just declare `Log` as a new data (user defined) type. But when you create an instance of it

```
Log log_flie;
```

memory is allocated for `name` and `msg`. Now you can allocate memory (dynamically) for elements of data member as

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    log_file.name[i] = malloc(N);  //N is the desired size
```

Similarly you can do for `msg`.

To free the *dynamically allocated memory*, call `free` as

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    free(log_file.name[i]);
```

---

If you want to allocate memory for `name` and `msg` dynamically then do as follows

```
typedef struct
{
    char **name;
    char **msg;
} Log;
```

Then

```
Log log_file;
log_file.name = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
log_file.msg = malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));
```